# Functionality difference between num = 1 << 4 and num |= 1 << 4

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

So if I understand bitwise operations correctly, `num = 1 << 4` shifts the 1 to the left 4 places by adding 0's to the lsb side of the number and if there's 1 in the way it changes to 0.

But if I do `num |= 1 << 4` does it "OR" the 1 with the bits on the way to the position it is being shifted to, or does it "OR" 0 with the bits on the way?

I know that using |= keeps the 1's on the way intact but I just want to know the functionality

Comment: `num |= 1 << 4` is a shortcut for `num = num | (1 << 4)`

Comment: What do you mean by "on the way"?

Comment: Keep in mind operator precedence as well. `<<` has higher precedence than `|=`, so the code will first calculate `1 << 4`, _then_ calculate `num = num | result`

Comment: Please note that C and C++ are two very different languages. Even simple things like bit-shift might have different wording in the respective language specifications. Please only tag the language you're really working with.

Comment: Since there's no obvious C++ aspect here the C++ tag should be deleted as per C and C++ tag usage policies. Questions about for example operator overloading of << need to be asked separately and tagged C++ only.

Answer (score 1):

All the "special" assignment operators like `|=` are formally called *compound assignment* and they all follow the very same rule (C17 6.5.1.6.2), stating that:

`E1 |= E2` is 100% equivalent to `E1 = E1 | (E2)` except that in the former case, E1 is only evaluated once.

Thus `num |= 1 << 4` is equivalent to `num = num | (1 << 4)`.

---

Please note that when shifting we should follow the good habit of pretty much always shifting an unsigned operand, `1u <<`. Since some cases like `1 << 31` invokes undefined behavior as the integer constant `1` is of type signed `int`.

Comment: As for when "only evaluated once" actually matters, here's an example: https://godbolt.org/z/j3GMqW577. The latter has an unspecified order of evaluation and may therefore give a different/unexpected result. A less exotic example might be `volatile` qualified hardware registers.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track with your understanding of bitwise operations.

In the expression `num |= 1 << 4`, the `<<` operator shifts the `1` four positions to the left, just like in `num = 1 << 4`. So, it results in `00010000` in binary.

The `|` operator performs a bitwise OR operation. When you use `num |= 1 << 4`, it effectively ORs the existing bits in num with the bits in the value 1 << 4. It doesn't change any bits that are already set to 1 in num. It only changes the bit at the fourth position from the right (counting from `0`) to `1` because it's the only bit set in `1 << 4`.

Here's how it works:

- Initial value of num: Let's say num is initially `00101010` in binary.
- `1 << 4` results in `00010000`.
- The `|` operation performs a bitwise OR, so you get `num` with the bit at the fourth position from the right set to `1`, and all other bits remain unchanged.
- So, the final value of `num` would be `00111010`,
- while if you did `num = 1 << 4`, the value of `num` would became `00010000`.

In summary, `num |= 1 << 4` sets the bit at the specified position to 1 without changing the other bits in num.